# PHP Function to identify color and switch image accordingly

Tags: php, wordpress, switch-statement

I am creating one function to identify color (from tag) and switch image accordingly. I am using wordpress Custom Post Type and custom texonomy (tags).

So what I exactly want to do is if product has three color than I will add three tags e.g. red, green, blue so the function should identify those tags and add appropriate image (color pattern thumbnail) to that tag.

Here I am trying to write but got stucked on the initial stage.

```
function color_options($texonomy=false){

        $tags = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, $texonomy, '', ',', '' );

        $tag = explode(",", $tags);

        $option = switch ($tag) {
            case 'red':
                return '<img src="url to red iage"';
                break;

            default:
                return 'No color';
                break;
        }

        return $option;
    }
```

**EDIT: Question Detail**

So I want to display the color image if it is defined as a tag. Means if one product has two color options red and green and it is defined as a tag than it should display two red and green pattern images. if it has three than three etc...

Hope this would be more clear now.

Comment: $texonomy should be $taxonomy as well I assume.

Comment: Can you please explain why negative vote? people put effort to give negative vote but never describe why???????

Comment: @cryptic yes you are right so I am passing like `product_tags`

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @melpomene I have already describe in second paragraph `So what I exactly want to do is if product has three color than I will add three tags e.g. red, green, blue so the function should identify those tags and add appropriate image (color pattern thumbnail) to that tag.` please let me know if you need more info

Comment: Yes, what I want to know is *what is your question?*

Comment: How can I pass single tag to the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function color_options($taxonomy = false)
{
    $tags = 'red,green,blue'; //get_the_term_list( $post->ID, $taxonomy, '', ',', '' );
    $tags = explode(',', $tags);
    $option ='';

    foreach ($tags as $tag)
    {
        switch ($tag) 
        {
            case 'red':
                $option .= '<img src="url to red image" />';
                break;
            case 'blue':
                $option .= '<img src="url to blue image" />';
                break;
            case 'green':
                $option .= '<img src="url to green image" />';
                break;
        }
    }
    return $option;
}

echo color_options();
```

Comment: thanks a lot for great help. I found this is useful but now I realized my own mistake. That switch will check for one value while I wan to display the color if it is exists ( in tags ). I need your suggestion either array_ke_exists() will work for it or switch will be fine?

Comment: please check my edited answer. If tags has green and red it will output a green and red image, if it has tags green, red and blue it will output all three. If it has no matching tags will output nothing.

Comment: This is great.. Thanks a lot. voted and selected..

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't mean "return" on the switch statement. See that the final "return $tag" is never reached.

Comment: oh yeh actually I didn't update that code but i just assign variable to switch and return that variable but still not working..let me update the code

Comment: What I mean is I'm not sure you can do this kind of assignment:
_$option = switch($tag){...}_ 
Why not _default: $ret='No color';_ and outside the switch, _return $ret_